# Read/Write permissions by different users

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I have a C# application that needs to be multi-user.
At this moment I already have an UserTable(SQL) that gives for each one an ID, Username, Password and an Access Level depending if the users are admins, basics or medium.

What I really need now is to check if two different users are workin in the same record!
If I have an "USER1" editing a record in a form and a "USER2" trying to edit the same record at the same time, that shouldn't be possible to the "USER2" because the record it's already in use by another user.

How can I check if a record is being edited to another user if I another user try to do the same?

Comment: It depends how you want to manage such situation. Do you want to keep record read-only? Do you want to let 2nd user begin editing but it can't be committed until first one saved/canceled his changes? Take also a look to [MSSQL locking](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213039(v=sql.80).aspx).

Comment: In general if you just want to check (before commit) what you need is just a "timestamp" column for each record (it's different, you UPDATE using timestamp in the WHERE condition, together with row id. If command returns 0 then it has been updated 'cause timestamp has been changed by someone else). Of course with each UPDATE you also change timestamp to a new value. For a more detailed overview see [Optimistic Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimistic_concurrency_control).

Comment: In contrast if you want prevent user from starting editing then check Pessimistic [Concurrency Control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concurrency_control).

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti,I want to keep the information in the form but all the fields read-only, disable all the saves/deletes/updates to the record and just give a message "the current record is already in use by..."

Comment: I just really need to disable all the fields in the C# forms if the record is open by another user...

Comment: You may lock that row when you start an editing session. If it fails then it's in use (because of editing) by someone else. But be careful: editing can be long, user may forget to close editing window, app may crash...all these things must be managed or you risk to keep a record locked for days (or forever). Pessimistic lock is somehow easier but trickier to setup.